# Is this statement correct?: Let $F$ be a vector field, then $\text {curl} (F)=0 \iff F$ is conservative.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Is this statement correct?: Let $F$ be a vector field, then $\text {curl} (F)=0 \iff F~$ is conservative.

I have a suspicion this is true but can't seem to prove it in either direction.

Could anyone tell me whether this is true and then give me some hints about how to go about proving it, thanks.

Here is what I have done:

(Proof in two dimensions but can extend to $n$ dimensions without issue)

Let $F~$ be a conservative vector field then $F=[G(x,y),H(x,y)]=[N_x,N_y]~ $for some function $N$ by definition of conservative vector fields. Then $\text{curl(F)}=N_{yx}-N_{xy}$.

Now $N_{yx}-N_{xy}=0$ and $\text{curl(F)}=0$ if the second order partial derivatives of $N$ are continous and we are done.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. It seems you are already familiar with typesetting in LaTeX, which is very good and encouraged to use. Also it is usually encouraged to show some own effort towards solving a problem as it can help (motivate) giving a better explanation.

Comment: Okay I will do that now.

Comment: I have attached what I have done, could you see what I'm missing to finish it. @John Ma

Comment: Your definition of conservative vector fields are not correct. (There should be one function instead of two $M, N$.

Comment: Ahhhhh of course namely the $S$ mentioned by mathreadler. Thanks, so I guess my proof is complete know. One more question how do we ensure that the second order partial derivatives are always continous? Otherwise the last step doesn't work and the implication is only true for certain vector fields.

Also is there any conditions which mean the implication read left to right is true?

Comment: Maybe we have to assume they are continous. Impose that as an extra restriction or something.

Comment: Okay thanks. Do you have any insight about my second question?

Comment: The reserve implication is true if your vector fields is defined on a simply connected domain.

Answer (score 0):

[A conservative vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field) is if it is the gradient of some scalar field. I.e. $F = \nabla S$. What you need to do is to show that the gradient of a scalar field can not have a non-zero curl.

Some hints on the way:

1. Use definition of conservative field above.
2. Use definition of curl

Try and put them together and see what happens.

Comment: Not sure about your hint, but one direction of the claim is actually not true in general.

Comment: Okay I will give it a go and hopefully can figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Would that be the left to right implication that is not true generally John.

Comment: @ChrisK You are right.